# Getting "Cannot_match_source_hash" error when trying to connect using spring boot using SAML. IDP is keycloack

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, saml, spring-saml

Hi Have create realms and client in keycloack. Trying to connect using SAML descriptor using spring boot but getting "Cannot_match_source_hash" in keycloack. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need keycloack connector in spring boot. But I am assuming that we can connect to any IDP using metadata descritor.

18:47:40,741 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-89) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=Public Library, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=client_not_found, reason=Cannot_match_source_hash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak error: client\_not\_found reason: cannot\_match\_source\_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278405/keycloak-error-client-not-found-reason-cannot-match-source-hash)