# Keycloak error: client_not_found reason: cannot_match_source_hash

Tags: keycloak, saml-2.0, opensearch-dashboards

Trying to configure AWS OpenSearch with Keycloak with SAML2.  I got XML SAML metadata from Keycloak realm -> Realm Settings General -> SAML 2.0 Identity Provider Metadata

and changed the entityId to "myEntityId". How to get correct xml or is there any setting in Keycloak to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change entityID (clientId) in keycloak same as "Service provider entity ID" of AWS.